# How to animate/show a hidden div?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

So I'm trying to show a div with a toggle transition when a link is clicked.

My code:

```
  $("nav ul li#about a").click(function (e) {
    $("div#about").slideToggle(200);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It works great, but I want this effect here:
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/
Scroll down and find "TRANSITIONS FOR OTHER PROPERTIES". Do you see that scale effect (first demo box)? THAT is what I want instead of the slideToggle. So I want this similar effect to TOGGLE... transition IN and OUT when link is clicked.

I hope you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery slideToggle method is really just a fancy wrapper around [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Since this transit plugin mimics the `animate` syntax we can build a toggle pretty easily.

```
$("nav ul li#about a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var about = $("div#about");
    if (about.css('opacity') == 0) {
        about.transition({ opacity: 1.0, scale: 1.0 });
    } else {
        about.transition({ opacity: 0.0, scale: 1.6 });
    }
});
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should check if the about div is invisible on click and choose which animation to execute based on that.

Comment: div#about is on display:none on css. I removed it and it shows the div and when i click on the link it disappears with the effect but when I click on the link again, guess what?..it's no longer a link :/i don't know what to do...